# take JSON input and store it in to an array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON input of

```
{
    "Categories": {
        "Facets": [{
            "count": 1,
            "entity": "Company",
            "Company": [{

                "entity": "Ford Motor Co",

                "Ford_Motor_Co": [{
                    "count": 1,
                    "entity": "Ford"
                }]
            }]
        }, {
            "count": 4,
            "entity": "Country",
            "Country": [{

                "entity": "Germany",
                "Germany": [{
                    "count": 1,
                    "entity": "Germany"
                }],
                "currency": "Euro (EUR)"
            }, {

                "entity": "Italy",
                "Italy": [{
                    "count": 1,
                    "entity": "Italy"
                }],
                "currency": "Euro (EUR)"
            }, {

                "entity": "Japan",
                "Japan": [{
                    "count": 1,
                    "entity": "Japan"
                }],
                "currency": "Yen (JPY)"
            }, {

                "entity": "South Korea",
                "South_Korea": [{
                    "count": 1,
                    "entity": "South Korea"
                }],
                "currency": "Won (KRW)"
            }]
        }, {
            "count": 5,
            "entity": "Persons",
            "Persons": [{
                "count": 2,
                "entity": "Dodge"
            }, {
                "count": 1,
                "entity": "Dodge Avenger"
            }, {
                "count": 1,
                "entity": "Major League"
            }, {
                "count": 1,
                "entity": "Sterling Heights"
            }]
        }]

    }
}
```

I need to get the values for entity in each level in to an array..

```
[Company, Ford Motor Co, Ford, ....... , Sterling Heights]
```

I am able to get thru the first level with the code

```
for (var k in h.Categories.Facets)
{

alert(h.Categories.Facets[k].entity);

}
```

How do I reach thru the innerlevels to get the values of entity??

Answer (score 1):

You should do a foreach on each entity. If you know how many levels there are you can nest loops. If not - probably should go for a recursive function.

**Edit**

Recursive function:

```
function getEntities(ent)
{
   alert(ent);
   for (var l in ent)
   {
      getEntities(ent[l].entity);
   }
}
```

Then use:

```
for (var k in h.Categories.Facets)
{
   getEntities(h.Categories.Facets[k]);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Im not familiar with recursive functions.. The levels will be different for each input, so I guess there is no other option other than recursive..

Answer (score 1):

The most general recursive answer:

> ```
> function getEntities(any) {
>     var entities = [];
>     if ('entity' in any​) {
>         entities.push(any.entity);
>     }
>     for (var prop in any) {
>         if (any[prop] instanceof Object && any.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
>             entities.append(getEntities(any[prop]));
>         }
>     }
>     return entities;
> }
> console.log(getEntities(h));
> ```

The line:

```
 if (any[prop] instanceof Object && any.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
```

Keeps numbers/nulls from bombing and the any.hasOwnProperty(prop) makes up for frameworks that like to attach to the Object prototype.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a recursive method that accepts an array and extracts the methods from it.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, you can use a recursive function to loop through every possible nested combo:

```
var allEntities = [];
function getEntities(obj)
{
   if (obj != null)
   {
       var entityName = obj["entity"];
       alert(entityName);
       if (entityName != null)
       {
           allEntities.push(entityName);
           var adjName = entityName.replace(/ /gi, "_");
           var entities = obj[adjName];
           if (entities != null)
           {
               for (var e in entities)
               {
                   var innerEntities = getEntities(entities[e]);
                   for (var inner in innerEntities)
                       allEntities.push(innerEntities[inner]);
               }
           }
       }
    }
}    

for (var k in h.Categories.Facets)
{
    alert(h.Categories.Facets[k].entity);
    getEntities(h.Categories.Facets[k]);
}
alert(allEntities.length);
```